# Can I activate profile in @PropertySource file in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles

I would like to activate a profile from my property file within application. Eventually I want to activate profile dynamically but I would like to start with static

My application

```
@SpringBootApplication @PropertySource("classpath:/my.properties")
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Component public static class MyBean {
    @Autowired public void display(@Value("${abc}") String abc) {
        System.out.println("Post:"+ abc);
    }
```

my.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=STAT
abc=ABC
```

My output is a proof that my.properties are read, but profile is ignored

> No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
>
> Display:ABC

Maybe I should explain what I want to achieve. My pre-Spring Boot application behaviour depends on environment, for example if `$ENV=DEV` development config is used. I want migrate to Spring boot and put config to profile, but I would like to keep environments unchanged.
I want implement that

`if $ENV=DEV then profile DEV is selected`

My idea is add `my.properties` with `spring.profiles.active=$ENV` but it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do that. `@PropertySource` are read too late to have any sort of influence on the application bootstrap.

`SpringApplication` is just a shortcut to something much more complete. You could read whatever property you need there and enable the profile before the app starts, something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String env = System.getenv().get("ENV");
  // Some sanity checks on `env`
  new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).profiles(env).run(args);
}
```